# How to update instances synchronously in Django models?

Tags: python, django, time, synchronization

I have 2 models:

```
class TranslatedLesson(models.Model):
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 amount_steps = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class TranslationStep(models.Model):
 lesson = models.ForeignKey(TranslatedLesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="steps")
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=TranslationStep, 
 dispatch_uid="update_lesson_date")
 def update_lesson_date(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  lesson = instance.lesson
  lesson.update_date = instance.updated_at
  lesson.save()
```

Every time I update `TranslationStep` model, I wanna update `updated_at` time, which `TranslatedLesson` has. But the code above gives me different results, as lesson is saved futher a little bit. Even if I delete `auto_now=True` and override .save method it doesn't give desired result.

```
 >>> step.updated_at
     datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 27, 7, 59, 24, 912420, tzinfo=<UTC>)
 >>> lesson.updated_at
     datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 27, 7, 59, 24, 919461, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

How to perform update synchronously?

Comment: Can you simply remove `auto_now` attribute on TranslatiedLesson, and do not override `save` method - just leave the `receiver` function in place to do its work?

Comment: @an0o0nym the thing is that I need to update `updated_at` in other places automatically

Comment: You need to explain why this matters. Of course the times will be a little bit different, nothing can ever happen truly synchronously. So what are you doing where you rely on the times being exactly the same? There is absolutely certain to be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want `TranslatedLesson.save()` to automatically `update_date`, you cannot use `TranslatedLesson.save()` here.  The solution is to bypass the call to `TranslatedLesson.save()` by [using `QuerySet.update()` instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
receiver(post_save, sender=TranslationStep, dispatch_uid="update_lesson_date")
def update_lesson_date(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    qs = TranslatedLesson.objects.filter(id=instance.lesson_id)
    qs.update(updated_at=instance.updated_at)
```

Comment: I wonder, how it works, cause in django docs it is said it can prevent even race conditions.

Comment: As the doc mentions, it works by issuing a direct SQL update query instead of going thru the model layer - which also explains how it can prevent some race conditions.